# Manage display of actions in datagrid

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

If have this in my `datagrids.yml` :

```
actions:
    update:
        type:          navigate
        label:         test.datagrid.address.update
        link:          update_link
        icon:          eye
        rowAction:     false
    default_address:
        type:          navigate
        label:         'Set as default address'
        link:          default_address_link
        icon:          star
        rowAction:     false
```

I want hide the `default_address` action when adsress is already the default address, how can i do this ?

I have try to add `action_configuration` but is not working for me..

Comment: Can you explain why action_configuration doesn't work for you? It should cover all the custom requirements